# Transaction Propagation issue

Tags: java, apache-camel, ejb, websphere, spring-transactions

We recently had a very unexpected issue in PROD which we manage to reproduce but we  still don't have a clear explanation of what is causing it and more importantly how to fix it.

Our system is a vendor workflow framework that offers us hooks to add our custom behavior. It is running on WebSphere Application Server and it is a mix of Camel and Spring and EJB. Initially it was pure EJB but a few years ago the vendor added Camel with a view of getting rid of application server.

Now the problem:

The start of processing is a Camel route which is transacted with **PROPAGATION_REQUIRED** attribute. Part of the processing there is a local call to an EJB method. There is not explicit setting for any of EJB methods exposed apart from being Container managed. This means the EJB call should get the implicit value of **REQUIRED**. Part of the EJB call there is data change happening. The reference to the EJB is obtained using some code like below:

```
String repositoryName = MBLLookupUtil.getInstance().getRepositoryName();
RepositoryInstanceFacadeHome facadeHome = MBLLookupUtil.getInstance().getRepositoryInstanceFacadeHome(
            repositoryName);
RepositoryInstanceFacade facade = facadeHome.create();

// Here is when the data change happens:
facade.doSomeWork();
```

The application logs show clearly that the EJB processing is happening in the same thread as the client. After making the call there is more work in the calling client when a Timeout exception happens.

We expect that both data change on client side and that changed as part of the EJB call will be roll backed, however the data changed by EJB call stays committed while the client side (Camel) gets roll backed.

In the spring application context we use `WebSphereUowTransactionManager` which is the IBM recommended way of configuring transaction manager:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>
```

Any hints about what could cause this or how we could further investigate would be great appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

As advised in tomgeraghty3's comment I made a code change to log the value of `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` and the result was **true**

**UPDATE 2:**
We found out where the issue was by spending hours of analyzing decompiled vendor code. The transaction propagation was configured in an application-context.xml file but it was also overwritten straight in the POJO code with an `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRED_NEW)` annotation. We proved that was the problem by removing the POJO class from the vendor jar and adding one with no annotation with the same package in one of ours. Very dirty just to prove our suspicion.

Now our bigger challenge would be to persuade the vendor address the issue. Hope it is just a bug and not an impacting change.

Comment: In your doSomeWork() can you add the line TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() to see if the Spring Transaction Manager has indeed created a Transaction?

Comment: the `doSomeWork()` is a method exposed by the third party vendor that we invoke to interact with their work flow so I cannot put that right there. However easy to change one of our hocks called as part of that work processing. I'll do this and update the question.

Comment: What is the super of the exception being thrown? Is it Exception or RuntimeException